# Simple PHP MySQL pagination (show more button, with parameters)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pagination

I'm trying to create a simple pagination for my website.
I have a table's rows with 3 value
**id (AI)

name

price**

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` ORDER BY `id`LIMIT 10
```

I use very simple MySQL request to show it, and JS/AJAX button to show more.
When it ordered by ID, it's easy to show more - I know the last ID, and I'm adding this info to the next request

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `id` > $lastid ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 10
```

But HOW can I create same pagination, if I'll order it by price?
It can be 100 items with same price, so I can't write

```
WHERE `price` > $lastprice
```

because it will show only 10% of all items with same price
Also, I can't write

```
WHERE `price` > $lastprice AND `id` > $lastid
```

because item with biggest id can be with less price.
Any ideas to make it work?
Thanks!
p.s. Actually it's not a real pagination, it's only one button "SHOW MORE" that takes next 10 items from server by AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by javascript, when calling the ajax function, pass it the number of rows already printed, then in mysql change the query to

```
..... LIMIT "value passed", 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need the `WHERE` clause in this case. The query should be like this

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` ORDER BY `price` DESC LIMIT <offset>, <results per page>
```

Where `offset` is the number of results to be skipped and `results per page` is the number of results to be returned (in your case 10). In order to calculate `offset` value you need the page number instead of last id for example. If you know that then (I assume is php on the backend):

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$offset = ($page - 1) * <resutls per page>;
```

This way you will get an offset of 0 on the first page, 10 on the second and so on.